# How do you get the probability distribution of the sum of random variables by using the inverse of the transform?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I read the following statement:

> If X and Y are independent random variables, the distribution of their
>   sum W = X + Y can be obtained by computing and then inverting the
>   transform $M_W (s) = M_X (s)M_Y (s)$.

Where $M_X(s)$ is the familiar transform:

$$M_X(s) = E[e^{sX}]$$

I was trying to find an explicit formula, but embarrassingly, yielded things that didn't make sense. I was trying to do this first for discrete r.v. and then for continuous. I am aware that there is a different way of doing this, namely, the convolution but I wanted to see a different approach.

So this is what I have so far:

Our goal is to find a formula for $p_W(w)$ (and we know it should be $\sum_x{P_X(x)P_Y(w-x)}$ .) So let start with the obvious:

$M_{W}(s) = E[e^{kW}] = \sum_w{P_W(w)e^{sw}}$

$M_{X+Y}(s) = E[e^{s(X+Y)}] = E[e^{sX}]E[e^{sY}] = \sum_x p_X(x)e^{sx} \sum_y p_Y(y) e^{sy}$

And then I guess I am unsure how to procede.

### ----

The suggested method was from [Tsitsiklis](http://vfu.bg/en/e-Learning/Math--Bertsekas_Tsitsiklis_Introduction_to_probability.pdf) probability book, page 163 (or section 4.2 from page 13 from that section), where it talks about convolutions.

Comment: I am not following what you are saying... The transform you are taking is Laplace transform. Inverting it is, well, non trivial. However in many cases you can spot the resulting Laplace transform. (for example when you multiply the Laplace transform of two binomial distribution with same value of $p$, you still get the Laplace transform of a different binomial distribution. I have never seen people actually inverting a Laplace transform to figure out the distribution of a random variable at the level you are studying.

Comment: The suggested method came from [Tsitsiklis](http://vfu.bg/en/e-Learning/Math--Bertsekas_Tsitsiklis_Introduction_to_probability.pdf) probability book, page 163 (or section 4.2 from page 13 from that section), where it talks about convolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with your $$\sum_x p_X(x)e^{sx} \sum_y p_Y(y) e^{sy}$$ and let $w=y+x$, i.e.  $y=w-x$, so this becomes $$\sum_x p_X(x)e^{sx} \sum_w p_Y(w-x) e^{s(w-x)}$$ and then rearrange this to  $$\sum_w \sum_x p_X(x) p_Y(w-x) e^{sw}$$ which is the moment generating function of $W$ $$\sum_w p_W(w)e^{sw}$$ where $p_W(w)=\sum_x p_X(x) p_Y(w-x)$.

Comment: How come the sum over $y$ became a sum of $w$, I guess thats the part I was a little confused... not sure if my short hand for only having one letter under the sum is confusing me, but why isn't the sum over $y = w-x$?

Comment: Given $x$, summing over $y=w-x$ and summing over $w=x+y$ amounts to doing the same thing.  Each term appears once in the sum either way

Comment: What I was worried about was that, the second summation you wrote over $w$ did not go over every value of $y$, since the first equation does go over all values of $y$. But that is exactly why you are going through all values of $w$m, to make sure it does go through all values of $y$ and that equality is preserved. Thanks! :)